# Easy way to sort getting images from a gallery using php?

Tags: php, image, file, readdir, opendir

Hello there good people of stackoverflow.

I have this code that basically get any photo i place in a folder called "pictures" and displays them on my page. Which is all good, and it works, with lightbox as well.

My main question is, can there be an easy way to display the photos in some form of order? i.e newest photos first?

```
<?php $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/pictures/');
while($file = readdir($handle)){if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
echo '<a href="pictures/'.$file.'" rel="lightbox"><img src="pictures/'.$file.'" border="0" /></a>';}}?>
```

I know the code is very vulgar and ancient, but its only for a sample page so it doesn't need to be massive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order them using php's filemtime(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

```
<?php 
   $path = dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/pictures/';
   $handle = opendir($path);
   $arrFiles = array();

   while($file = readdir($handle))
   {
      if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..')
      {
          $arrFiles[filemtime($path.$file)] = '<a href="pictures/'.$file.'" rel="lightbox"><img src="pictures/'.$file.'" border="0" /></a>';
      }
   }
   arsort($arrFiles);
   foreach ($arrFiles as $file)
   {
       echo $file;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Just got a massive page of errors. on line 26 which is

{
          $arrFiles[filemtime($handle.$file)] = '<a href="pictures/'.$file.'" rel="lightbox"><img src="pictures/'.$file.'" border="0" /></a>';
      }

Comment: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for Resource

Comment: @SeanKerwin Sorry. My original code had an issue with it. I was trying to append $handle to $file. Of course that didn't work. Check above for the fix.

Comment: Seems to work fine! I've just uploaded 4 images, one by one, and the last one i uploaded was the first image displayed.

Kudos.